# Gitlab-runner dose not see my local repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to create a docker-compose file that contains a GitLab instance and also a GitLab-runner.

Everything works fine and I have also been able to register the runner, but it does not see my local network in order to clone the project properly:

[image]

This is my docker file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:16.2.3-ce.0
    container_name: gitlab
    hostname: '0.0.0.0'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'http://0.0.0.0:83'
    ports:
      - '83:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '22:22'
    volumes:
      - gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
      - gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
    network_mode: host

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:v16.2.1
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    depends_on:
      gitlab:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - gitlab_runner_config:/etc/gitlab-runner
    network_mode: host

volumes:
  gitlab_config:
  gitlab_logs:
  gitlab_data:
  gitlab_runner_config:
```

Dose anyone know what exactly I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not fully sure on gitlab's docker setup, but I'm assuming you are trying to get `gitlab-runner` to clone a repo from the `gitlab` container ? If so, `gitlab-runner` should hit the `gitlab` container on port 80 and not 83. In your port mappings you have mapped container port 83 to host port 80. Alternatively you can change your port mapping to `83:83`.